# How can I safely install a frameless melamine wall cabinet that has a thin pressboard backing, and no hanging rail?

Tags: walls, installation, cabinets, carpentry, hanging

This frame-less wall cabinet is melamine with a thin press-board backing, and it has no hanging rail. The press-board backing is set back from the rear of the cabinet about 5/8". The cabinet seems pretty heavy for it's size.

It was a shop project about 20 years ago and just takes up workbench or countertop space; not sure why anyone got an "A" on it without a way to mount it! I'm sure that if I just screw through the press-board to mount it, it will simply break and tear through the press-board, even if I fill the space behind the press-board.

It will be a stand alone, with no cabinet or wall next to it, so I can't screw through the sides.

I'm thinking that if I glue and screw a filler behind the press-board, it might hold, but it still won't be attached to the cabinet except for the thin backboard, and I just don't want to have to worry about it once it's hung and filled with misc. hardware.

Any great ideas would be welcome!

[image]

Comment: The term to google is "french cleat".  Here is an example of it being used to mount a cabinet very much like yours: [French Cleats And How To Use Them – Secure Cabinet Hanging](https://homefixated.com/french-cleats-and-how-to-use-them-secure-cabinet-hanging/)

Answer (score 2):

Install a "cleat" on the wall and hang the cabinet on the cleat. Screw through the thin backing into the cleat. The cleat would be thick enough to protrude slightly past the sides and top. One or two screws holding the cleat onto the wall would ideally be into a stud. Two other screws holding the cleat could be into drywall near the ends of the cleat to resist rotation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Cut a piece of wood so that it fits horizontally in the back of the cabinet, ends flush to the side pieces of the cabinet.  It is the same depth as the space behind the cabinet (1 inch?).  Maybe a 1x4 inch board.
2. Cut second piece the same as first.  Put second piece on the bottom edge of the back of the cabinet and do leave it there.
3. Mount 1st piece of wood on wall securely across 2 studs.  Use a level to get it horizontal.  Use several screws or bolts according to weight of cabinet & expected contents.
4. Hang cabinet by back lip of pressboard on the 1 x 4 you have mounted to the wall.
5. Drill thru top and sides of pressboard and use screws to attach cabinet to 1 x 4 mounted on wall.

Now weight of cabinet is resting on a horizontal piece of wood which itself is securely on the wall.  Weight is transferred thru solid top and sides of pressboard.

Bottom piece of wood behind cabinet is just to fill space so bottom is same distance from the wall as top and the cabinet cannot swing back against the wall.  All the weight is on the top one.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is drill 2 holes one in each side near the top and back, pass a bolt through the hole with fender washers on the inside and outside next to the particleboard.  On the outside the  bolt goes through a steel angle one on each side.  Bolt the angle to the wall through studs.